# Trying to use different array data structure in a jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I came across this **[random image rotator](http://jsfiddle.net/stonecold111/KU7Zx/8/)**

```
var theImages = new Array() 
    theImages[0] = 'img1"'  theImages[1] = 'img2"'......   
var shuffled = [];    
while (theImages.length) {
    shuffled.push(theImages.splice(Math.random() * theImages.length, 1));
}            
$(document).ready(function(){        
    //Runs Script each time there is an <li>
    $("#news li").each(function(index){                
        //Puts Image in front of everything in <li>
        $(this).prepend('<img src="'+shuffled[index]+'">');            
    });

});
```

And I integrated it into a jQuery Carousel. You can see **([my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stonecold111/YrPc7/11/))** here.  The problem is that the array structure I want to use for the Carousel is different from the rotator's. **The rotator uses**:

```
var theImages = new Array() 
theImages[0] = 'img1"'
theImages[1] = 'img2"'
theImages[2] = 'img3"'
```

But I want to use the following for **the Carousel** because I want to input a link to each picture as well.

```
var theImages = [
['img1','url_1'],
['img2','url_2'],
['img3','url_3']];
```

The outcome I'm looking for would be like:

```
<div id="carousel1"> 
<div class="1"><a href="url_1"><img src="img1"></a></div>
<div class="1"><a href="url_2"><img src="img2"></a></div>......
```

From what I've read, I have to use `for in loop` to assign the data and can't simply use what the image rotator is using:

```
$("#carousel1 .1").each(function(index){    

$(this).prepend('<a href="'+imgPath+''+shuffled[index]+'"><img 
src="'+urlPath+''+shuffled[?url](?url)+'"></a>');
```

Is that true? Is there any way that allows me to populate the images as well as the urls in the Carousel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, never use `for ... in` for arrays. All you have to do is change

```
'<img src="'+shuffled[index]+'">'
```

to

```
'<a href="'+imgPath+shuffled[index][1]+'"><img src="'+urlPath+shuffled[index][0]+'"></a>'
```

since the image path is the first element of the inner array, and the link is the second one.

See [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json) for more info.

(I assume `imgPath` and `urlPath` are actually defined somewhere and contain URLs. If not, you should remove them.)

Comment: Yes, the imgPath and urlPath are defined. `var imgPath = "/pic/";` 
`var urlPath = "/url/";`. I made the change you suggest, but I got an undefined error. Am I doing it wrong? **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stonecold111/YrPc7/13/)**

Comment: I don't get any error, but the code to shuffle the array is actually wrong. `.splice` returns an array of the removed elements, so you have to add `[0]` to get the first (and only) removed element: `shuffled.push(theImages.splice(Math.random() * theImages.length, 1)[0]);` It only seemed to have been correct before, but `shuffled` was actually an array of arrays with single elements. http://jsfiddle.net/YrPc7/14/

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your source array (the shuffled values) only contains one value but the final resulting one you want to have pairs of values. That extra data needs to come from somewhere, the computer can't just invent it.

The easiest way to do this is to modify the shuffle code and instead of shuffling single strings shuffle pairs of strings instead.

i.e. something like

```
var theImages = new Array() 
theImages[0] = ['img1"', data1]
theImages[1] = ['img2"', data2]
```

Comment: Isn't that what the OP is already doing in `var theImages = [ ['img1','url_1'], ['img2','url_2'], ['img3','url_3']];` ?

Comment: @FelixKling I don't think so, I could be wrong but if I'm reading the question right that's how he does it without the shuffling.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0;i<theImages.length;i++){
    newTheImagesArray.push([theImages[i],theImages[i]])
}
```

This should work for what you want

Comment: That generates the link and image how exactly?

Comment: I understood that the link attached to the image was to be to the image,
This takes the array of images in the form `["url1","url2","url3"...]' and puts it into the form ["url1":"url1","url2":"url2","url3":"url3"...]